# e-commerce + realcommerce with the same stock

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, prestashop

I'm searching for a system that can provide a e-commerce and a program that deal about real customers.

The two applications could be completely different but I need to update the stock directly the  if something is purchased online or offline.

I searched for Prestashop but I cannot make real transactions with the application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for Point of Sale software to use with e-commerce software.

[AspDotNetStorefront](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com) is my favorite e-commerce platform and there are add-ons available that allow it to work with QuickBooks Point of Sale - as well as other [Point of Sale products](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/c-112-point-of-sale.aspx).

In addition, they have a phone order entry feature for administrative users logged on to the web store that allows admins to place orders as customers that could be used to place orders for offline customers or customers you are helping over the phone.